# Sending and recieving with TCP, using a socket more than once (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

EDIT: Turned out I was using the same port twice. Will leave this here for anyone googling though, threads like htis have helped me in the past.

I am currently working on a project where I have a highscorelist on a server and a client, with the two syncing the data on them, saving in XML. I have it all working pretty much, but I keep getting the exception "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address ", and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. To me the code looks fine, since I close the `TcpClient` in `Update` before it moves on to `Recieve`. Can anyone spot what I am missing, or explain to me what I've gotten wrong? I'm decently new to this so some actual code in the explanation would help alot!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Update();
        Recieve();

    }
```

Server sending to client:

```
public static void Update()
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument highScore = new XmlDocument();
        highScore.Load("hs.xml");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int placering = i + 1;
            stringList.Add(highScore.SelectSingleNode("highScores/score" + (placering)).InnerText);

        }
        string toSend = stringList[0] + stringList[1] + stringList[2] + stringList[3] + stringList[4];

        string adress = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 82;
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        tcpClient.Connect(adress, port);
        NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        Byte[] bSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
        NetworkStream tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        tcpStream.Write(bSend, 0, bSend.Length);
        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

Server recieving from client:

```
public static void Recieve()
    {
        //skapa ett TcpListener objekt
        IPAddress myIp = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener tcpListener;
        int port = 82;


        tcpListener = new TcpListener(myIp, port);
        tcpListener.Start();   //Throws the exception
        Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

        int messageSize;
        Byte[] bMessage = new Byte[256];


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                messageSize = socket.Receive(bMessage);
                break;
            }
            catch { }
        }

        //konvertera till string och skriv ut
        string message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < messageSize; i++)
        {
            message += Convert.ToChar(bMessage[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            SaveScore(int.Parse(message[i].ToString()), i + 1);
        }

        socket.Close();
    }
```

Both methods are in the same `Program.cs` in a seperate solution than the game.

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: tcpListener.Start()  @apocalypse

Answer (score 0):

You should also stop your TcpListener in your Receive method, is it possible it is still open from a previous run of your application?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was one of those simple things, after basically rewriting the methods I discovered that the methods for sending and recieving were both using port 82 after I copy pasted in from a different project... Yup. Thanks for those trying to help though lol